# Discrete change of multiple variables?

Tags: summation

Suppose I have a sum of the form:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^m c_{i,j}$$

And I sub :

$$ j+ i \to x$$

And,

$$ i-j \to y$$

Then:

$$ \frac{i+j}{2} = x$$

And,

$$ \frac{i-j}{2} = y$$

If I sub:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^m c_{ \frac{x+y}{2} , \frac{x-y}{2} }$$

How do I figure out the new bounds of summation..?

Comment: Do you mean $c_{j,i}$ in the first sum? which requires corresponding changes in the rest of the post, and might help you resolve your question.

Comment: Good point, fixed that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give an answer for the infinite case:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}  c_{i,j}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \sum_{\begin{matrix}y=-x\\ \color{red}{\text{step} \ 2} \end{matrix}}^{y=x} c_{x,y} $$

The "$\color{red}{\text{step} \ 2}$" meaning that the values taken by $y$ are:

$$y=-x, \ -x+2, \ -x+4 \ \cdots x. \tag{1}$$

Why that ? let us write the $i,j$ tables under this form:

$$\text{Abscissas i : } \ \ \begin{matrix}
..&..&..&..&..&\\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
0&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
\end{matrix} \ \ \ \ \ 
\text{Ordinates j : } \ \ \begin{matrix}
..&..&..&..&..&\\
4&4&4&4&4&\cdots\\
3&3&3&3&3&\cdots\\
2&2&2&2&2&\cdots\\
1&1&1&1&1&\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\
\end{matrix}$$

From which we deduce the tables of $x$ and $y$:

$$\text{Values of  x : } \ \ \begin{matrix}
..&..&..&..&..&\\
4&5&6&7&8&\cdots\\
\color{blue}{3}&4&5&6&7&\cdots\\
2&\color{blue}{3}&4&5&6&\cdots\\
1&2&\color{blue}{3}&4&5&\cdots\\
0&1&2&\color{blue}{3}&4&\cdots\\
\end{matrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\text{Values of y : } \ \ \begin{array}{rrrrrc}
..&..&..&..&..&\\
-4&-3&-2&-1&0&\cdots\\
\color{red}{-3}&-2&-1&0&1&\cdots\\
-2&\color{red}{-1}&0&1&2&\cdots\\
-1&0&\color{red}{1}&2&3&\cdots\\
0&1&2&\color{red}{3}&4&\cdots\\
\end{array}$$

(check that $i+j=x$ and $i-j=y$).

In the table of $x$ values, one sees that $x$ can take (along diagonals with "equations" $i+j=x$, one of them has been highlighted in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$) all positive integer values, indicating that it has to be taken as the "driving" variable. $x$ being fixed, the corresponding values taken by $y$ (in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$) are indeed described by (1).